# how do i center a button in this scenario

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

i have these lines of code putting my done button in a toolbar.
i have no idea how to center it. Ive tried many things online but i cant find one that works.

```
self.closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(close)];
    self.closeButton.enabled = YES;
    self.closeButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.closeButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
    self.closeButton.width = 32.000;
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `UIBarButtonSystemItem` with `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` before and after your closeButton.

```
UIBarButtonItem* flexibleSpace = 
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
```

Comment: can you show me exactly how it should look next to my code im getting a unused variable flexiblespace